An Extended Bayes Theorem Problem

A student has 3 squared and 7 ruled notebooks. But the student has forgotten one notebook at the university. He pulls out 1 notebook from his backpack at home. What is the probability that this is a ruled notebook?

My try:
Let $H_{1}$ and $H_{2}$ be the events that he left squared and ruled notebooks respectively, also $A$ be the event of picking up a notebook.
Then, $P(H_{2}|A)$ is to be determined.
$$P(H_{2}|A) = \frac{P(A|H_{2})}{P(A|H_{1}) + P(A|H_{2})}$$
We have, $P(H_{1}) = \frac{3}{10}$, $P(H_{2}) = \frac{7}{10}$ and $P(A) = \frac{1}{10}$.
Not getting how to proceed.

Simplest is to ignore that a notebook was forgotten, since no info is available on the forgotten notebook.  So the answer must be the same as if no notebook was forgotten.

You can use the total probability theorem.
Let $L_r$ be the event that he left a ruled notebook at school,let $L_s$ be the event that he left a squared notebook at school, and let $R$ be the event that he picked a ruled notebook out of his backpack.
Then $$P(R)=P(R|L_r)P(L_r)+P(R|L_s)P(L_s)=\frac{2}{3}\frac{7}{10}+\frac{7}{9}\frac{3}{10}=\frac{7}{10}$$
